# How to do processes asynchronous?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, struts

Is it possible to process the services separately in struts2.0. 
There are three different submit buttons in my JSP-File. Whenever the buttons are clicked each should process separately without stopping other processes.

Answer (score 1):

There's support for calling methods asynchronously by just using `@Async` annotation. The best documentation I found is on springsource website: [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html)

**EDIT**: Regarding 'denial service' mentioned by Stephen - spring provides you with configurable thread pool so you won't exhaust cpu of application server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  It is a bit difficult to get right though:

- Your server needs to keep track of what "processes" (or threads) are currently running.
- Your server has to implement some mechanism for delivering the results of the processing.
- Your server has to guard against accidental or deliberate "denial service" if some user clicks the submit button lots of times.

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax call in async mode.Jquery.ajax is a convenient method to process separtely without stopping other process.In ajax call you can trigger the button click event.